# SubSonic 2.1 and Oracle problems

Tags: subsonic

Please if anyone knows the answer, I´m still looking for 3 days and nothing..

I make some test with subsonic, SqlServer and MySql and with some little changes in the web.config  file everything was good.

But now, I need to work with Oracle . I maked the changes and next command runs

**DataTable qry = ModeloDados.DB.Select().From("CARGO").ExecuteDataSet().Tables[0];**

But if i type the **ModeloDados.** the class doesn´t appear. Ony appear the next :

**DB  ,   Schemas  ,   SPs   ,  Tables   ,    Views**

With the SqlServer or MySql everything is good.The class Cargo appear. I think it´s not configuration in the Oracle because the above command runs, but i need to work with the class

some like **Cargo c = new Cargo**

But the class doesn´t appear.

There something i missing ?

Thanks for any help.

THE CONFIGURATION :

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="oracle" connectionString="Data Source=xxx.x.xx.xx:1521/bancoteste;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=user;Password=xxx;" providerName="System.Data.OracleClient"/>
</connectionStrings>


<SubSonicService defaultProvider="oracle" enableTrace="false" templateDirectory="">
    <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="oracle" type="SubSonic.oracleDataProvider, SubSonic" 
           fixDatabaseObjectCasing="true" 
           connectionStringName="oracle" 
           generateRelatedTablesAsProperties="true" 
           fixPluralClassNames="false" 
           generatedNamespace="ModeloDados" 
           regexIgnoreCase="true" 
           removeUnderscores="false" 
           setPropertyDefaultsFromDatabase="true" 
           generateNullableProperties="true" 
           useExtendedProperties="true" useUtc="true"/>
    </providers>
</SubSonicService>


    <compilation debug="true">
        <buildProviders>
            <add extension=".abp" type="SubSonic.BuildProvider, SubSonic"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that there are errors when the build provider runs against Oracle.

You'll need to hunt those down, perhaps by doing a build with [SubCommander](http://subsonicproject.com/docs/Command_line) instead. I haven't used the build provider in a long time, but if memory serves, it's not that great at putting the errors into visual studio where you can see them.

Comment: Thanks for your help!! Was my fault, I forgot the primary key on the table .. Now it´s working ... Thanks again for your help and sorry for my distraction....

[]s.