# How can I change database from SQL Server to Oracle with SubSonic?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, subsonic

I write code with SubSonic 2.1.1 and used MSSQL. The project must be run with Oracle now.
I changed web.config, and it does not work. Can someone give me a sample which changes database only - changes web.config with subsonic and the rest doesn't change?

Table name in MSSQL is "Name" but in Oracle is "NAME". Can subsonic
generate "Name" code for oracle?

Comment: what are the changes to web.config. how does it "not work"?

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095313/subsonic-2-1-and-oracle-problems) question your connections string will need to look like the following (obviously replace xxxxx with your database values):

```
<connectionStrings> 
  <add name="oracle" connectionString="Data Source=xxxxxxxx;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xxxxx;Password=xxxxx;" providerName="System.Data.OracleClient"/> 
</connectionStrings>
```

Re. your second question, Oracle is not case sensitive. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095767/subsonic-oracle-and-properties-case) question for more details